# Get grandparent context inside function

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know a more elegant way to be able to access parent's parent object inside a function?

```
var obj = {
    subobj : {
        func1 : function() {
            // here 'this' will refer to window
            // i want to access obj instead
        }
    }
};

var obj = {
    func1 : function() {
        //  i know 'this' here will refer to bj
    }
}
```

i also tried

```
var obj = {
    subobj : {
        func1 : function() {
            // even 'this' will refer to window
        }.bind(this)
    }
}
```

but even in this bind example 'this' will refer to window because it is outside.

**I CAN DO**

```
var _this = obj;
```

inside func1 but i **DON'T** want to use this ugly trick.

I basically want to get obj context inside func1 OR add obj context to subobj.
I can't think of anything right now, any suggestion from you guys?

THANKS

Comment: You can access `obj` inside your function `func1`. It is already captured inside closure. Why would you need to mess with context? Simply use `function(){ console.log(obj);}`

Comment: Yeah i have mentioned direct obj access but if i change obj to obj2 in future i would have to check wherever it is used inside itself and change there as well.

Comment: *"... but if i change obj to obj2 in future i would have to check wherever it is used inside itself and change there as well."* That's why you use an IDE that has refactoring support for variable renaming!

Comment: So you want to move `subobj` to a different obj and make your function automagically use new root as a context? What if future maintainer somehow know where you live? :)

Comment: I usually comment my work so this would not be an issue for future maintenance, but i do agree with you that saving obj in a variable is more declarative

Answer (score 2):

First of all. You don't really need to mess with the context since you already have `obj` accessible from within your function `func1`.

```
var obj = {
    subobj : {
        func1 : function() {
            //use `obj` here
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }
};
```

Or if you for some reason want to access obj as this. Do the following

```
var obj = {
    subobj : {
        func1 : function() {
            //this is now obj here. Go suffer maintainer!
        }.bind(obj);
    }
};
```

Comment: I am trying to build loosely coupled modules. And accessing the module (in this case 'obj') is all i need, from there i can go wherever and access whatever inside that module. Thnx anyway!